# How to loop through xm document which have attribute with symbol in name

Tags: php, xml

I'm looping through a xml file, but I want to use an attribute name which has the "-" in it.

```
    foreach( $xml as $person)
    {
        echo 'Name: '.$person->Name.'<br />';
        echo 'Home address: '.$person->home-address.'<br />';
        echo 'Away address: '.$person->away-address.'<br />';
    }
```

The "-" symbol breaks the script, how do I make this work? I don't want to rename the attribute.

Comment: try { } e.g $person->{'home-address'}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use curly brackets around the variable name:

```
$person->{'away-address'}
```